# Configuring django ec2 instance to use a virtualenv

Tags: python, linux, django, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

[image]

I am working to set up a django project on ec2 with an Ubuntu 14.4 LTS instance. I want to write my code using python 3 and django. I'm following http://www.nickpolet.com/blog/deploying-django-on-aws/1/ and have been able to get the django start page working. Previously I added django to both the default python 2.7 and the installed python 3.4.

I've created a virualenv and if I run the program after activating the virualenv I can use the python 3.4 interpreter. However, while testing I got the following error when I open the amazon ip address:

```
Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response, line 111
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.6
```

As you can see the default python interpreter is in use. How do you force django to use the python 3 virtualenv?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26560636/django-1-7-installation-using-pyvenv-with-python-3-4-in-ubuntu-trusty-14-04 says that virtualenv is broke in ubuntu 14.04. You need to make sure to update it prior to creating your virtualenv. Also, when you installed django where you in a active state in your virtual env?

Comment: I used virtualenvwrapper, and I think it worked fine . My virtualenv was in the active state and I could see packages being installed in the python 3.4 directory

Comment: I appreciate you looking at this. However I Iooked your link above and there doesn't seem to be a connection to using a python 3 interpreter. just to reiterate i can get django working fine on python 2.7, but I want to use python 3 .

Comment: Understood and thank you, I will take another look at it

Comment: I have a follow up at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28830917/python-uwsgi-setup-on-ec2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue using apache and mod_wsgi and was unable to figure it out so I used this guide here and went with nginx and uwsgi and it worked awesome in like 30 minutes. [Here](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html) is a quick tutorial on how to use uwsgi