# Nginx not serving django image

Tags: python, django, nginx, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04

[image]

I'm trying to follow the tutorial at http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html. I've gotten down to http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html#basic-nginx-test. Following the directions I have:

```
(env1)ubuntu@ip-172-31-28-196:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/nginx start
(env1)ubuntu@ip-172-31-28-196:~$ ls
host_type.py  requirements.txt  test.py  tproxy
```

However when I go to my ubuntu ec2 instance at:

```
http://52.10.**.***:8000/media/media.jpg
```

The request times out. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: - the config file

```
# mysite_nginx.conf    

# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream django {
    # server unix:///path/to/your/mysite/mysite.sock; # for a file socket
    server 127.0.0.1:8001; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
}    

# configuration of the server
server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen      8000;
    # the domain name it will serve for
    server_name 52.**.***.**; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
    charset     utf-8;    

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste    

    # Django media
    location /media  {
        alias ./media;  # your Django project's media files - amend as required
    }    

    location /static {
        alias ./static; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    }    

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     ./uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    }
}
```

nginx error log:

```
2015/03/03 18:06:06 [emerg] 1989#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2015/03/03 18:06:06 [emerg] 1989#0: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2015/03/03 18:06:06 [emerg] 1989#0: still could not bind()
```

[image]

Comment: Did you link your config file to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`?

Comment: I did, I've followed every step up to the basic test listed in the tut.

Comment: Can you connect to it on the server itself (ie by SSHing to the server then issuing a `telnet localhost 8080`)

Comment: Can you post your nginx config minus your personal info? You may have to look at the logs in /var/log/nginx/error.log and track down the issue. That should help a bit

Comment: Hi Selcuk, I'm not experienced with networking. Does that mean entering 'telnet localhost 8080' on the ec2 ubuntu command line?

Comment: Electrometro , the file is above.

Comment: (env1)ubuntu@ip-172-31-28-196:~$ telnet localhost 8080
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

Comment: @user61629 Did you look at the logs?

Comment: I've added a piece of the error logs, its all the same error repeating.

Comment: Is port 8000 open for that instance on the security group assigned to this EC2 machine?

Comment: Delete the log with `sudo rm -rf error.log` and then try running the nginx again and then look at the log again

Comment: yes Marcos, I've added an image of the security rules.

Comment: You should change your configuration file to have the static files path inside your virtual env folder. you need to use the full path too.

Comment: Electrometro, I deleted the logs then ran:(env1)ubuntu@ip-172-31-28-196:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart
 * Restarting nginx nginx
   ...done. I rechecked the error log, and its empty with 0 bytes although it was recreated

Comment: Did you visit the site and try to access the static file again since you delete the log?

Comment: yes "http://52.10..../media/media.jpg"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72182/discussion-between-electrometro-and-user61629).

Comment: So again, the key point is that all paths in the config file should be absolute.