# Setting up Unix Socket with Nginx and Django

Tags: python, linux, django, sockets, nginx

I'm trying to follow the tutorial at http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html. I've gotten everything working down to http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html#using-unix-sockets-instead-of-ports. I am working with an ubuntu 14.4 instance on amazon EC2:

The Nginx config file starts with:

```
# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream django {
    server unix:///path/to/your/mysite/mysite.sock; # for a file socket
    # server 127.0.0.1:8001; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
}
```

I am confused about the syntax of setting up a unix socket. I've looked at several sources including http://pymotw.com/2/socket/uds.html , [Permission denied - nginx and uwsgi socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22071681/permission-denied-nginx-and-uwsgi-socket) and https://serverfault.com/questions/124517/whats-the-difference-between-unix-socket-and-tcp-ip-socket

It looks like they all start with "///" If I understand correctly the path just points to the root directory of ( in my case ) the django project and the path has to end with ".sock" . Does this seem right ?

edit: I've made the uwsgi config file, but I'm trying to run this with the --socket switch instead:

The Nginx config file now starts with:

```
# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream django {
 server unix:///tmp/mysite.sock; # for a file socket
# server 127.0.0.1:8001; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
}
```

Following what I think you are saying, I'm running uwsgi on socket /tmp/mysite.sock .

```
(env1)ubuntu@ip-172-31-28-196:~$ uwsgi --socket /tmp/mysite.sock --wsgi-file test.py --chmod-socket=664
```

When I open:

```
http://52.10.----:8000/
```

In firefox I see:

```
502 Bad Gateway
```

The error log for nginx shows:

```
2015/03/04 15:08:44 [crit] 18398#0: *3 connect() to unix:///home/ubuntu/mysite.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 64.56.60.130, server: 52.10.200.38, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:///home/ubuntu/mysite.sock:", host: "52.10.200.38:8000"
```

edit 2: I commented out the django related stuff -

```
 # mysite_uwsgi.ini file
 [uwsgi]    

 # Django-related settings
 # the base directory (full path)
 #chdir           = /path/to/your/project
 # Django's wsgi file
 #module          = project.wsgi
 # the virtualenv (full path)
 #home            = /path/to/virtualenv     

 # process-related settings
 # master
 master          = true
 # maximum number of worker processes
 processes       = 1
 # the socket (use the full path to be safe
 socket          = /tmp/mysite.sock
 # ... with appropriate permissions - may be needed
  chmod-socket    = 664
 # clear environment on exit
 vacuum          = true
```

I tried:

```
(env1)ubuntu@ip-172-31-28-196:~$ uwsgi --ini /home/ubuntu/tproxy/tp/mysite_uwsgi.ini --wsgi-file test.py
```

but got a 502 error again.

```
2015/03/04 17:50:00 [crit] 18842#0: *1 connect() to unix:///tmp/mysite.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 64.56.60.130, server: 52.10.200.38, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:///tmp/mysite.sock:", host: "52.10.200.38:8000"
```

EDIT 3:

```
(env1)ubuntu@ip-172-31-28-196:~$ uwsgi --ini /home/ubuntu/tproxy/tp/mysite_uwsgi.ini --wsgi-file te
st.py
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /home/ubuntu/tproxy/tp/mysite_uwsgi.ini
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.9 (64bit) on [Wed Mar  4 18:41:43 2015] ***
compiled with version: 4.8.2 on 03 March 2015 02:58:28
os: Linux-3.13.0-44-generic #73-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 16 00:22:43 UTC 2014
nodename: ip-172-31-28-196
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /home/ubuntu
detected binary path: /home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/env1/bin/uwsgi
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
your processes number limit is 7862
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /tmp/mysite.sock fd 3
Python version: 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:08:40)  [GCC 4.8.2]
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x205e710
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 145520 bytes (142 KB) for 1 cores
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 0 seconds on interpreter 0x205e710 pid: 18868 (default app)
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 18868)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 18869, cores: 1)
```

edit 4: - just noticed

```
♥SIGINT/SIGQUIT received...killing workers...
worker 1 buried after 1 seconds
goodbye to uWSGI.
VACUUM: unix socket /tmp/mysite.sock removed.
```

So everytime I exit uWSGI, the socket is being removed. Maybe I should turn the vaccum option off so the chmod settings are preserved?

I changed:

```
vacuum          = false
```

but...

```
 (env1)ubuntu@ip-172-31-28-196:/tmp$ sudo chmod 777 mysite.sock
 (env1)ubuntu@ip-172-31-28-196:/tmp$ ls -la
 total 8
 drwxrwxrwt  2 root   root   4096 Mar  4 19:32 .
 drwxr-xr-x 22 root   root   4096 Mar  4 19:06 ..
 srwxrwxrwx  1 ubuntu ubuntu    0 Mar  4 19:32 mysite.sock
 (env1)ubuntu@ip-172-31-28-196:/tmp$ cd /home/ubuntu/
 (env1)ubuntu@ip-172-31-28-196:~$ ls
 host_type.py  requirements.txt  test.py  tproxy
 (env1)ubuntu@ip-172-31-28-196:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart
  * Restarting nginx nginx
    ...done.
 (env1)ubuntu@ip-172-31-28-196:~$ uwsgi --ini /home/ubuntu/tproxy/tp/mysite_uwsgi.ini --wsgi-fi
 st.py
 [uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /home/ubuntu/tproxy/tp/mysite_uwsgi.ini
 *** Starting uWSGI 2.0.9 (64bit) on [Wed Mar  4 19:36:42 2015] ***
 .....
 spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 1568, cores: 1)
 ♥SIGINT/SIGQUIT received...killing workers...
 worker 1 buried after 1 seconds
 goodbye to uWSGI.
 (env1)ubuntu@ip-172-31-28-196:~$ cd /tmp
 (env1)ubuntu@ip-172-31-28-196:/tmp$ ls -la
 total 8
 drwxrwxrwt  2 root   root   4096 Mar  4 19:36 .
 drwxr-xr-x 22 root   root   4096 Mar  4 19:06 ..
 srw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu    0 Mar  4 19:36 mysite.sock
```

so chmod is not preserved..

edit 5:

```
(env1)ubuntu@ip-172-31-28-196:/tmp$ uwsgi --ini /home/ubuntu/tproxy/tp/mysite_uwsgi.ini --wsgi-file
 test.py --chmod-socket=777
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /home/ubuntu/tproxy/tp/mysite_uwsgi.ini
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.9 (64bit) on [Wed Mar  4 20:54:21 2015] ***
compiled with version: 4.8.2 on 03 March 2015 02:58:28
os: Linux-3.13.0-44-generic #73-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 16 00:22:43 UTC 2014
nodename: ip-172-31-28-196
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /tmp
detected binary path: /home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/env1/bin/uwsgi
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
your processes number limit is 7862
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /tmp/mysite.sock fd 3
Python version: 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:08:40)  [GCC 4.8.2]
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x18b4790
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 145520 bytes (142 KB) for 1 cores
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
failed to open python file test.py
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 1858)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 1859, cores: 1)
--- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---
[pid: 1859|app: -1|req: -1/1] 64.56.60.130 () {36 vars in 555 bytes} [Wed Mar  4 20:54:34 2015] GET
/ => generated 21 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 2 headers in 83 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
```

Now getting internal server error:

```
2015/03/04 19:33:26 [crit] 1531#0: *1 connect() to unix:///tmp/mysite.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 64.56.60.130, server: 52.10.200.38, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:///tmp/mysite.sock:", host: "52.10.200.38:8000"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to say server `unix:///tmp/mysite.sock;` and then in the uwsgi ini file you make, create the unix socket in `/tmp/`

Comment: Thanks for looking at this man, I've changed the nginx config as you suggested. as far as the uwsgi config, I assume you are talking about http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html#configuring-uwsgi-to-run-with-a-ini-file ? If so where do you put this file, I don't think it says where in the tut.

Comment: I usually just put it in the same folder with the settings.py and wsgi.py file. You will see why later when you setup emperor. It is no problem, last night i setup this same setup again on amazon ec2 to try it out and it works great. :)

Comment: double check your configs and make sure you are putting the .sock in the same spot nginx is looking for it.

Comment: Does uwsgi say anything when you start it?

Comment: for now just change the chmod-socket line to 777 until you get to the end of the tutorial and then go back and change it to 664. Chmod is what determines the permissions for the files. Have you tried googling any of these errors?

Comment: No you want the vacuum on so it will delete the socket. uwsgi has to be running for nginx to serve up your django application. That socket will get created every time uwsgi starts up. So go delete it and then start uwsgi with vacuum set to to true. The tutorial does a pretty good job at explaining that exactly what you will need to modify.

Comment: OK figured it out , I ran  uwsgi --ini /home/ubuntu/tproxy/tp/mysite_uwsgi.ini --wsgi-file
 test.py --chmod-socket=777 from the wrong directory and test.py was not there

Comment: Do you mind looking at 1 more ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28883356/502-bad-gateway-connecting-nginx-to-django-via-socket